# excel vba shape.copy works in one instance, but not in another

Tags: excel, image, vba, comments, shapes

If (in Excel 2010) I create a shape object as follows:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(inpicfile, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, widpts1, htpts1)
```

I can then copy that picture to the clipboard with one statement:

```
sh.Copy
```

But if I have a picture in a cell's comment, and I create my shape as follows:

```
Set sh = Activecell.Comment.Shape
```

then a sh.copy statement gives me Run Tim error '1004'; Application-defined or object-defined error.

Anyone know why?

I have found the following way to copy the comment picture, but I would like to understand the difference between the two 'shapes'.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
c.Comment.Visible = True
sh.Select
sh.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
c.Comment.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

(c is a range object for a cell.)

Comment: I think this is just an Excel specific limitation.  If you try to copy the comment bubble without VBA, you are prevented from doing that as well.  You can copy the text but not the bubble itself.  Is the goal to do something with the `Shape` somewhere else?  Or are you trying to copy the comment to paste onto another cell?